# Merging multiple layers in folder with Graphical Model Builder in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis-3, layers, qgis-processing, merge, qgis-modeler

I am trying to create a graphical modeler that merges all the layers in a folder. I am using QGIS 3.10.12. I saw in some post that there used to be `saga:mergeshapeslayer` but its not included in the present QGIS version.

I know it can be done manually directly from QGIS, but i am trying to automate a workflow that has other processes. I would be interested in any solution that can open/browse to a location and merge all the files in that folder/directory.

I am using QGIS 3.10.12-A Coruña.

Comment: What about a native QGIS tool: ["Merge vector layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers)? Get more info via `processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:mergevectorlayers")`